# Oracle 11g SQL Loader getting 951 error

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

SQL Loader im gettting 951: Error calling once/load initialization ORA-26002: Table table has index defined upon it.

Actually im using  parallel=true direct=true options, for parallel execution i removed multiple table indexes and trigger. Still i getting same error.

Comment: Showing your table (and remaining index) definitions, control file and sample data is usually helpful for SQL\*Loader questions. You're hitting a restriction with parallel loads, and it seems like you haven't removed all indexes (maybe there's a PK you didn't include?). You might need to change your approach, e.g. non-parallel and/or conventional load, or load into a staging table and then copy into the real one, or use an external table; but not enough info here to know what's appropriate for you.

Answer (score 0):

A few options.

1. Drop index and recreate it after load.
   or
2. `parallel=true`
   or
3. use sqlloader parameter `skip_index_maintenance = true` and rebuild index after load